# How to print this table in combined form C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, sequence, tabular

I need to print this table

2
0
4 2
3 3
6 4 2
6 6 6
8 6 4 2
9 9 9 9

I have written this code for the following result

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int N = 9; 
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i += 3){   
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j +=3) {
            cout << i << " ";  
        }       
        cout << endl; 
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for(int i = 2; i <= N; i += 2){    
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j -= 2) {
            cout << j  << " ";    
        }         
        cout << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Result:

0
3 3
6 6 6
9 9 9 9

2
4 2
6 4 2
8 6 4 2

Required Result:

2
0
4 2
3 3
6 4 2
6 6 6
8 6 4 2
9 9 9 9

Comment: 1) change your logic to create the numbers such that for both you have the outer loop index correspond to the line number 2) combine both into one

Comment: I asked how do I combine them and your answer is , combine them ! Wow

Comment: read the comment again more carefully....

Comment: I suggest to create sub-functions: one to create multiple of 3, on for decreasing even numbers. then write both loop to have i = 0 -> 4. then merge loop.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int N = 9; 
    for(int i = 2; i <= N; i += 2){    
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j -= 2) {
            cout << j  << " ";    
        }         
        cout << endl; 
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j +=3) {
            cout << j << " ";  
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const auto n = 4;
    auto count = 0;
    for (auto i = 2; i <= n * 2; i += 2)
    {
        for (auto j = i; j > 0; j -= 2)
            std::cout << j << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (auto j = 0; j < (i == 2 ? i : i + 2); j += 3)
            std::cout << count * 3 << " ";
        ++count;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Corrected...

A little near to the answer
2
0 ==>   true
4 2
0 3 ==>  should be 3 3
6 4 2
0 3 6  ==>  should be 6 6 6
8 6 4 2
0 3 6 ==>  should be 9 9 9

Comment: You should add this to the question instead of putting it here.

Comment: Yes I thought of that while answering.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: No, I have mentioned the mistakes as "should be"

Comment: Is it `9 9 9` or `9 9 9 9` because your question looks different... And it is working for me...

Comment: sorry its `9 9 9 9`

Comment: Then use `(i == 2 ? i : i + 2)` instead of just `i` in the second for loop condition. I edited that in your answer too.

Comment: There are three loops

Comment: Okay, now your code is working properly...

Comment: Yes .. Thanks alot . Though I don't know what `auto coun`t is used for ! Anyways it helped . You can answer my question about `auto count` if you want.

Comment: `auto`(short for **automatic** type) is a keyword in C++ (and only works since C++11, not in C) that analyses the value you give it during initialization and *auto*matically guesses its type. Example: **[1 is taken as int]**, **[1.0f as float]**, **[1.0 as double]**, **['1' as char]**, **["1" as const char *]**, etc. For more information, go here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: I edited my answer to make it short as possible... Check it out now...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach for case when you're providing number of repeats (like in [@Ruks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720729/9252020) answer):

```
void printSequence(unsigned int repeats)
{
    int n = 2;
    for(int i = 1; i < repeats; i++)
    {
        n+=2*i;
    }
    //n - number of all numbers in sequence for given number of repeats

    int step = 0;
    int numsPerRow = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=step)
    {
        for(int j = numsPerRow; j > 0; j--)
        {
            std::cout << 2*j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < numsPerRow; j++)
        {
            std::cout << step+numsPerRow-1 << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        step+=2;
        numsPerRow++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
void print_sequence(unsigned long long const repeat = 4, unsigned long long const i = 0)
{
    for (auto j = (i + 1ull) * 2ull; j > 2ull; j -= 2ull)
        std::cout << j << " ";
    std::cout << (repeat > 0ull && repeat < -1ull ? "2\n" : "");
    for (auto j = 0ull; j < i; j++)
        std::cout << i * 3ull << " ";
    std::cout << (repeat > 0ull && repeat < -1ull ? std::to_string(i * 3ull) + "\n" : "");
    if (repeat < -1ull && i + 1ull < repeat)
        print_sequence(repeat, i + 1ull);
}
```

**Edit:** The shortest and strongest method I can think of...

And call it like this:

`print_sequence();`

If you don't want 4 times:

`print_sequence(10)`

It will repeat it as many times you want...

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Comment: I am not at that level of C++ . We are just going throught for loops . And this problems needs to be solved with simple for loops .

Comment: @TrevorPhilip Which part of it is **"that level of C++"**? If you want, you can remove the if statements inside the for-loop, that won't make a big difference (would add extra spaces at the end of each line)...

Comment: You can see my answer . That's my level of understanding C++

Comment: I don't think of it more than simple arithmetic and for-loops always look the same in syntax, nothing new there. Just try reading it carefully and tell me where you stop.

Comment: So can you help my correcting my answer rather than understanding yours ? Because I lack of time , and I am near to the answer .